# Figuring out pin configuration for a small SMD transistor

Tags: surface-mount, pins

The data sheet of the dual transistor [IMZ1A](http://rohmfs.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/transistor/bipolar/umz1n.pdf) shows pin layout as:

[image]

But the chip I received looks like this:

[image]

There is a small dot on top left, but according to the datasheet, pin 1 should be on top RIGHT. Is there a way to make sure which is pin 1?

Comment: Are you sure you got the IMZ1A and not one of the other two?

Comment: I'm sure. It's written IMZ1AT108 on the packet.

Comment: So maybe the large white ellipse is denoting pin 1..

Comment: Or maybe what you see is a bottom view. Grab your multimeter and test the junctions, that's the best way to be sure.

Comment: Thanks. I tested the pins with multimeter. Pin 1 is the large white ellipse.

Comment: ["Stadium"](http://s1.hubimg.com/u/8304660_f520.jpg)

Comment: @EMFields Well, I've learned something today, so it's a good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a multimeter to check the transistor junctions.

Put it in diode testing mode and verify each of the transistors using the pinout on the datasheet as a guide. This way you will be able to determine the correct packaging.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like maybe the die is mounted upside down on the lead frame in the SC-74 and right side up on the other parts (or the opposite), hence the 'backwards' numbering. This only affects asymmetrical parts and not the dual transistors with two similar parts.

The rounded mark ("stadium" as EM says) should be pin 1, since the **Z1** should be readable with the part oriented the same as the others. Still worth checking as Bruno says.

[image]